# What does "had better be regarded as sacrosanct" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this in *Word by Word* by Kory Stamper:

> Memos begin, “Editorializing has no place in definitions,” or
>   “Godlove’s psychophysical defs of color names and their references had
>   better be regarded as sacrosanct.” Sir, yes, sir!

I get the *"editorializing"* part alright but having trouble in underatanding what "had better be regarded as sacrosanct" imply? I mean what would happen if they were not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Had better be

“Had better be” is grammatically correct but sounds old-fashioned.  It is a form of the subjunctive.

> x had better be regarded as sacrosanct.

This can be understood to mean:

> x ought to be regarded as sacrosanct.
>
> x should be regarded as sacrosanct.

By saying,

> x had better be regarded as sacrosanct,

You are saying

> It would be best if x were regarded as sacrosanct.

The author of your example follows this with “Sir, Yes, Sir!” which is what a lower-ranking soldier would say to a commanding officer.

Because that context is so ***out of place*** here, That is your clue that the author is making a joke.  In other words, the narrator does not fully agree (or agree at all).

Comment: The *had better* construction is not a form of the subjunctive. It doesn't even mean the same thing. Both of them can be replaced by *should*, but consider: *It is important that he be there* is the subjunctive. *It is important that he should be there* is the periphrastic subjunctive. *It is important that he had better be there* doesn't work at all.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Accepted answers here on ELL and other resources elsewhere on the web do describe “had better” as a form of subjunctive.  I’ll add citations, but I recognize that all sources do not agree.

Comment: It looks like *had* in *had better* was originally a verb in the subjunctive mood several centuries ago. I don't see how knowing this helps anybody understand the construction in today's English.